# How to send powershell command to pc through usb with python?

Tags: python, linux, windows, powershell

I'm making an rpi based terminal in python and I want to run a powershell command on my computer. How can I send a command to a usb device

Comment: Do you mean you want to send a Powershell command from a Python script running on your RasPi to be executed on a Windows PC? How/where does the PC *"see"* the RasPi?

Answer (score 0):

You could run `socat` on your Windows PC to read from serial and execute whatever you receive - if you like big security holes Try adding `socat` tag to attract the right folk if that's an option.

Or you could run a Python script that sits in a loop reading from serial and then using `subprocess.run()` to execute the commands it receives.